# Iterating over NSMutableArray Not Working Properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I'm having an issue iterating over an NSMutableArray of custom objects. Whenever I run the following code, it will iterate over the array 6 times, despite there only being 2 objects in the NSMutableArray object.

```
//Configure the Settings Screen
[self addSection:^(JMStaticContentTableViewSection *section, NSUInteger sectionIndex) {

    section.title = @"Twitter Accounts";

    //alloc and init the twitterSwitchesArray to store the switches used in the view
    self.twitterSwitchesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.twitterAccounts count]];

    NSLog(@"LOADING: twitterAccounts Array count: %i", [self.twitterAccounts count]);

    for(MessageBlastSavedTwitterAccount *twitterAccount in _twitterAccounts)
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring: %@", twitterAccount.twitterAccountDescription);

        //Configure the Twitter Setting Switch
        [section addCell:^(JMStaticContentTableViewCell *staticContentCell, UITableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {

            UISwitch *twitterSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
            twitterSwitch.accessibilityLabel = twitterAccount.twitterAccountDescription;
            twitterSwitch.on = [self switchShouldBeFlippedForTwitterAccount:twitterAccount.twitterAccountDescription];

            NSLog(@"LOADING: Twitter account %@, should be enabled: %i", twitterAccount.userEnteredDescription, [self switchShouldBeFlippedForTwitterAccount:twitterAccount.twitterAccountDescription]);

            [self.twitterSwitchesArray addObject:twitterSwitch];

            [twitterSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(flippedTwitterSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

            staticContentCell.reuseIdentifier = @"UIControlCell";
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.textLabel.text = [twitterAccount userEnteredDescription];
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"210-twitterbird.png"];
            cell.accessoryView = twitterSwitch;
        }];
    }
}];
```

I get the following output:

```
2012-10-04 20:47:27.703 MessageDraft[1206:c07] LOADING: twitterAccounts Array count: 2
2012-10-04 20:47:27.703 MessageDraft[1206:c07] Configuring: coryb
2012-10-04 20:47:27.704 MessageDraft[1206:c07] LOADING: Twitter account @coryb, should be enabled: 1
2012-10-04 20:47:27.705 MessageDraft[1206:c07] Configuring: cocoaapp
2012-10-04 20:47:27.706 MessageDraft[1206:c07] LOADING: Twitter account @cocoaapp, should be enabled: 1
2012-10-04 20:47:27.708 MessageDraft[1206:c07] LOADING: Twitter account @coryb, should be enabled: 1
2012-10-04 20:47:27.709 MessageDraft[1206:c07] LOADING: Twitter account @cocoaapp, should be enabled: 1
2012-10-04 20:47:27.713 MessageDraft[1206:c07] LOADING: Twitter account @coryb, should be enabled: 1
2012-10-04 20:47:27.714 MessageDraft[1206:c07] LOADING: Twitter account @cocoaapp, should be enabled: 1
```

I have even tried a manual way (below) to iterate over the array, and I still have the exact same issue:

```
// The self.twitterAccounts count returns a 2, so this should only repeat twice.
    for(int i = 0; i < [self.twitterAccounts count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%i", i);

        //Configure the Twitter Setting Switch
        [section addCell:^(JMStaticContentTableViewCell *staticContentCell, UITableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {

            UISwitch *twitterSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
            twitterSwitch.tag = i;
            twitterSwitch.on = [self switchShouldBeFlippedForTwitterAccount:_twitterAccount.description];

            self.twitterAccount = [_twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:i];

            NSLog(@"LOADING: Twitter account %@, should be enabled: %i", _twitterAccount.userEnteredDescription, [self switchShouldBeFlippedForTwitterAccount:_twitterAccount.description]);

            [self.twitterSwitchesArray addObject:twitterSwitch];

            [twitterSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(flippedTwitterSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

            staticContentCell.reuseIdentifier = @"UIControlCell";
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.tag = i;
            cell.textLabel.text = [_twitterAccount userEnteredDescription];
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"210-twitterbird.png"];
            cell.accessoryView = twitterSwitch;
        }];
    }
}];
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what's JMStaticContentTableViewSection, but probably the problem is when the addCell method gets called.Could you provide the documentation for this method? I suspect that it gets executed more than once at every loop.

Comment: The documentation for the JMStaticContentTableView is here: https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMStaticContentTableViewController

Comment: The for loop is behaving as expected (iterating twice), the problem is with the addCell method getting called repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of [JMStaticContentTableViewController](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMStaticContentTableViewController).

The `addCell:` method is not getting called multiple times. The `JMStaticContentTableViewCellBlock` block you pass *into* the  `addCell:` method gets called as part of the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of the controller.

It does this so that you can properly configure `UITableViewCells` and they get reused efficiently.

After reviewing your code above, I'd suggest that you iterate through twice, once to configure your `twitterSwitchesArray` properly, and another with the code you'd like called in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

You can look at an example of doing a for loop, and running loop-safe code inside of the `JMStaticContentTableViewCellBlock` [right here](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMStaticContentTableViewController/blob/master/SettingsExample/SettingsExample/WifiViewController.m#L96-L136).

`JMStaticContentTableViewController` is designed so that you can still "think" of it in the same way as the traditional delegate-based `UITableViewController` model, but using blocks instead.

That's why `JMStaticContentTableViewCellBlock` passes in a `UITableViewCell` instance, this is so you can treat it like what you would be handed from the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method of `UITableView`. It also passes in `JMStaticContentTableViewCell` model object instance so that you can configure a few things that wouldn't make sense or wouldn't be possible on the standard `UITableViewCell` object, like `tableViewCellSubclass` or `cellHeight`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not the `for` loop, not even this method, but inside `addCell:`. The block you set in `addCell:` is getting called multiple times.

Comment: Yes, that looks like it's the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

it is internal issue, it would be better to use ((ClassName*)[mutableArray objectAtIndex:i])